# how do I turn off ihp telemetry

Tags: ihp

how do I turn off ihp telemetry? A bad setting for a work laptop. I think it should be default off.

I tried adding this variable to .envrc without any luck:

```
~/work/1031exchange.ai/blog
❯ cat .envrc
PATH_add /nix/...
IHP_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

~/work/1031exchange.ai/blog
❯
```

adding an environment variable to start script didn't work:

```
~/work/1031exchange.ai/blog 25s
❯ tail start
eval "$(direnv hook bash)"
eval "$(direnv export bash)"

# You can define custom env vars here:
# export CUSTOM_ENV_VAR=".."

export IHP_DISABLE_TELEMETRY=1

# Finally start the dev server
RunDevServer

~/work/1031exchange.ai/blog
❯

~/work/1031exchange.ai/blog
❯ ./start
direnv: loading ~/work/1031exchange.ai/blog/.envrc
direnv: ([direnv export bash]) is taking a while to execute. Use CTRL-C to give up.
direnv: export ~PATH
[("ihpVersion","1.0.0"),("os","darwin"),("arch","aarch64"),("projectId","82b7d1ce2f58ced12309a248fcc693fb5f2bf4a7437084c6e1c87a2de106bbf17ec347ace8d28d7406d8d8ec73da3fd6bb9a66c06fa9c776275a3793b9c6c9b5")]
GHCi, version 9.2.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
package flags have changed, resetting and loading new packages...
IHP Telemetry is activated. This can be disabled by setting env variable IHP_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.envrc` project file is overwritten by IHP. It's best to configure this in your global `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`. Defining it globally also makes sure that Telemetry is disabled across all your IHP projects.

Comment: any idea why adding the variable to start script didn't work?